# UNIX AWK : Get Logs from 24 Hours

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract data from the log files for last 24 hours .
I am trying

```
awk -v d="$(date -d'24 hours ago' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" '$1" "$2>=d &&/ERROR/' data.log
```

This does find  patterns  and works well if the dates are the first thing on a line for e.g

```
2016-03-06 1:59 ERROR --GOOD
2016-03-06 2:04 ERROR --GOOD
```

, but for others it brings every line that has the word "**ERROR**" and **ignores** the date range.

My data.log file looks like :

```
ERROR [Thrift:28] 2016-03-04 01:26:07,949 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message. <br/>
ERROR [Thrift:24] 2016-03-04 01:26:07,952 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:9] 2016-03-04 01:26:07,958 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:3] 2016-03-04 01:26:07,961 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:7] 2016-03-05 01:26:07,966 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:30] 2016-03-06 01:26:07,979 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:29] 2016-03-06 01:26:07,989 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
ERROR [Thrift:31] 2016-03-06 01:26:07,991 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:224 - Error occurred during processing of message.<br/>
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing `$1" "$2` to a date but `$1` contains `ERROR` and `$2` contains `[Thrift:31]`, etc. Try the obvious `$3" "$4` instead.

When any program doesn't behave as you expect, it's a good idea to add a few `print`s so you can see the values of variables to make sure they are what you think they should be.

Comment: Ed , Many thanks that was right on target!!